# Is such way of passing objects with status information between services and controllers valid?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm quite new to WebAPI development, but I've got some general C# programming experience.
I must pass some data from service to controller and sometimes also between services.
I used to use `IActionResult` when I simply was passing services response through controller to external front end like Angular. The I simply returned `StatusCodeResult` when there was no content and `ObjectResult` otherwise. But now I came to the point where I must call one service in another service and such approach is difficult for me.

I've came up with something like that:

```
public class ServiceResponse {
    private object? Content { get; set; }
    private Type? ContentType { get; set; }
    public string? StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess => StatusCode >= 200 && StatusCode < 300;

    public ServiceResponse(int statusCode, string? statusMessage) {
        StatusMessage = statusMessage;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public T? GetContent<T>() {
        if (Content is T content) {
            return content;
        }
        return default;
    }

    public void SetContent<T>(T content) {
        Content = content;
        ContentType = typeof(T);
    }
}
```

Is such approach generally valid, or am I reinventing the wheel?
What is the best way of passing optional content with status information like HTTP Status Code or StatusMessage?

I've already got the problem with my idea, because I cannot easily check what will be written. This interface may be an example (comment above is what is being returned on success):

```
public interface IUserService {
    /// <returns>User? - user or null</returns>
    public ServiceResponse GetUser(int id);
    /// <returns>List<User> - list of users (may be empty)</returns>
    public ServiceResponse GetAllUsers();
    /// <returns>int - database id generated for the user</returns>
    public ServiceResponse CreateUser(User user);
    /// <returns>null - no content</returns>
    public ServiceResponse UpdateUser(User user);
    /// <returns>null - no content</returns>
    public ServiceResponse DeleteUser(int id);
}
```

Is it possible to differentiate content type that will be returned, but also make this type optional (some methods will return only StatusCode with no content). I know about generics, but as far as I know it's not possible to make this type optional so If I used generics this will always have to be `ServiceResponse<Type> MyMethod();`, and simple `ServiceResponse MyMethod();` will cause an error.

What do you want about my approach?

Comment: Have you looked into FluentResults? https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults

Comment: Arguably such implementation breaks abstractions for corresponding layers. Usually `IUserService` should not know anything about status codes (which is HTTP layer abstraction). It should now about users, hence it should return users (and maybe relevant abstraction like mentioned earlier `FluentResults`).

Comment: _"I know about generics, but as far as I know it's not possible to make this type optional so If I used generics this will always have to be ServiceResponse<Type> MyMethod();"_ nobody forbids to create two types - `ServiceResponse ` and `ServiceResponse<T> : ServiceResponse`

Comment: @GuruStron I understand your point, but if this is an interface used to simply inject service in ASP.NET Core context, than is there any real gain from separating the status codes from the data itself? In simple scenario, where a controller calls a service that is doing one thing it's reasonable, that you will add status code in controller, but what if this service uses another services and one of them will fail. You can always throw an Exception from the service that failed and rethrow it to controller, but isn't such solution less readable and slower?

Comment: @Aenye_Cerbin if the scenario is "simple" the question is - is it worth introducing services at all. As for exceptions - [I'm not a big fan of using them in such cases either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76707773/2501279), but such model looks to tightly coupled to concepts of HTTP (`IsSuccess => StatusCode >= 200 && StatusCode < 300`  especially), while you can use something similar but much more clear (what for example is status code 219 from `IUserService` point of view, why it can return it?) with something like `FluentResults`. Obviously this hugely depends on the concrete case.

Comment: How about using dynamic type?